# Java File release resource

Tags: java, spring, file

I am using SpringFramework Web MVC and inside the servlet handleRequestInternal, I created a variable to access a file in the local filesystem, i.e.

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,......
{
......
 File file = new File(rssPath);
 if( !file.exists() ) {
  file.createNewFile();
  FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(rssPath);
  outFile.write(rssJson);
  outFile.flush();
  //file = null;
 }
}
```

The question is, if I don't set the file to null, the file will still be in use and I can't write to it.

I have to wait a few seconds, probably until GC comes to collect.

Looking at the File API, I don't see any method such as close() to release the resources.

So how do I destroy the file reference properly (without setting it to null, am I missing something ?) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't close Files. But you HAVE to close `FileInputStream`, `FIleOutputStream`, `FileReader` and `FileWriter`. Otherwise these Streams (and File-Handles) will not be GCed. (until the Object holding the Stream is GCed)

EDIT:
Do this in a `finally`-Block, to be sure close is called.

Comment: Damn i missed that, closing the FileWriter!! unbelievable. Thanks.

Comment: Closing a file in a finally block is not a good idea:  it means that your file will be closed even if there is an error(!)  To make a reliable program, you really only want to close it if there is no exception.   See http://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/surprising-outrageous-file-handling/   Instead of using a finally block, it would be better to use a catch block and remove the file that may be partially written.

Comment: The Streams may be closed in a finally-block. But you are right in that case, that there have to be some kind of error handling if an exception occours. In the catch-block there could still be the delete-file code you mentioned in the blog-post. But there is still an error in your code, and the file may not be deleted. if the close() in the catch-block throus an exception.

Answer (score 4):

How about `close()` method on FileWriter object?

`outFile.close();`